# query $and with empty value in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I create an API for showing video depends on conditions. Query URL will be like `/api/video/?hashtag=xxx&category=yyy&author=zzz&post_by=username`

The find() function like this

```
const videoFound = await Video.find({
    $and: [
        { hashtag },
        { category },
        { author },
        { post_by }
    ]
})
return res.status(200).send(videoFound)
```

Sometime user just search for hashtag and category only `/api/video/?hashtag=xxx&category=yyy`, but the result return empty []. The author, post_by are empty. The result should show if there are empty condition.

How do I handle this? If user leave a condition empty, it should show the result as well.

Thank you

Comment: $and : All condition must be true in order to evaluate then return result since empty array is falsy value so i would suggest you to use $or

Comment: Did you try building the query object dynamically based on the user request?